# Shiny reactive value error, table in module not responding to selectInput choice (input$var)

Tags: r, shiny

Recently I've been trying to develop a Shiny App that uses 2 imported tables and creates a 3rd table that reflects the sum of the first two tables. In addition, I'm also trying to filter the imported tables by an input$choice from a selectInput expression.

The problem I'm currently running into is this line within the table modules:

`data <- reactiveValues(table = test[test$num == reactive({input$var}),])`

The code will run if I replace the reactive({input$var}) with an integer that exists within test$num, so I guess I'm just not sure how to call on the input$var value as an integer? Can anyone help me with this problem? The code is below and using an edited mtcars dataset from base R.

````
### Libraries
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

### Data----------------------------------------
set.seed(0)
x <- data.frame(num = rep(c(1:5),2))
test <- cbind(mtcars, x)

module1 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      # initialise the reactive data object for the table
      data <- reactiveValues(table = test[test$num == reactive({input$var}),])
      
      # render the table
      output$table <- renderDT({
        datatable(data$table,
                  editable = TRUE)
      })
      
      # update the underlying data
      observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
        data$table <- editData(data$table, input$table_cell_edit)
      })
      
      # return the data as a reactive
      return(reactive(data$table))
    }
  )
}

module2 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      # initialise the reactive data object for the table
      data <- reactiveValues(table = test[test$num == reactive({input$var}),])
      
      # render the table
      output$table <- renderDT({
        datatable(data$table,
                  editable = TRUE)
      })
      
      # update the underlying data
      observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
        data$table <- editData(data$table, input$table_cell_edit)
      })
      
      # return the data as a reactive
      return(reactive(data$table))
    }
  )
}

module_add <- function(id, data_input_1, data_input_2) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      # do the calculations
      data_table <- reactive({
        data_input_1() + data_input_2()
      })
      
      # render the table
      output$table <- renderDT({
        datatable(data_table())
      })
    }
  )
}

modFunctionUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  selectInput(ns("var"), "Variable", choices = test$num)
  dataTableOutput(ns("table"))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  modFunctionUI("table_1"),
  modFunctionUI("table_2"),
  modFunctionUI("table_3")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # call the modules for the editable tables and store the results
  amptable <- module1("table_1")
  refreshtable <- module2("table_2")
  
  # call the module for the table that takes inputs
  # the reactives musn't be evaluated
  module_add("table_3",
                data_input_1 = amptable,
                data_input_2 = refreshtable)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)```


EDIT: Could you explain how the call works? In my module when I add another argument to my module function and use reactive({input$var}), an error comes up 

Error in ==: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types. 

I guess this is an issue with how I'm calling the input$var from the main UI but I don't quite understand how the modules interpret the input values.


module1 <- function(id, choice) {

data <- reactiveValues()
      observeEvent(choice, {data$table <- test[test$num == as.numeric(choice),]}, ignoreInit = FALSE)

}
 
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("var",
              "Variable",
              choices = test$num,
              selected = NULL),
  modFunctionUI("table_1"),
  modFunctionUI("table_2"),
  modFunctionUI("table_3")
)
          
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # call the modules for the editable tables and store the results
  amptable <- module1("table_1", reactive({input$var}))
}
````

Answer (score 0):

You had a few issues other than using `as.numeric(input$var)`.  Try this

```
### Libraries
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

### Data----------------------------------------
set.seed(0)
x <- data.frame(num = rep(c(1:8),4))
test <- cbind(mtcars, x)

module1 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      # initialise the reactive data object for the table
      #data <- reactiveValues(table = test[test$num == reactive({input$var}),])
      data <- reactiveValues()
      observeEvent(input$var, {data$table <- test[test$num == as.numeric(input$var),]}, ignoreInit = FALSE)
      # render the table
      output$table <- renderDT({
        #data$table <- test[test$num == as.numeric(input$var),]
        datatable(data$table,
                  editable = TRUE)
      })
      
      # update the underlying data
      observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
        info = input$table_cell_edit
        str(info)
        i = info$row
        j = info$col
        v = info$value
        data$table[i, j] <<- (DT::coerceValue(v, data$table[i, j]))
        # data$table <<- editData(data$table, info)
      })
      
      # return the data as a reactive
      return(reactive(data$table))
    }
  )
}

module2 <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      # initialise the reactive data object for the table
      # data <- reactiveValues(table = test[test$num == reactive({input$var}),])
      data <- reactiveValues()
      observeEvent(input$var, {data$table <- test[test$num == as.numeric(input$var),]}, ignoreInit = FALSE)
      # render the table
      output$table <- renderDT({
        datatable(data$table,
                  editable = TRUE)
      })
      
      # update the underlying data
      observeEvent(input$table_cell_edit, {
        info = input$table_cell_edit
        str(info)
        i = info$row
        j = info$col
        v = info$value
        data$table[i, j] <<- (DT::coerceValue(v, data$table[i, j]))
        #data$table <<- editData(data$table, info)
      })
      
      # return the data as a reactive
      return(reactive(data$table))
    }
  )
}

module_add <- function(id, data_input_1, data_input_2) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      # do the calculations
      data_table <- reactive({
        rbind(data_input_1(),data_input_2())
      })
      
      # render the table
      output$table <- renderDT({
        datatable(data_table())
      })
    }
  )
}

modFunctionUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(ns("var"), "Variable", choices = unique(test$num) ),
    dataTableOutput(ns("table"))
  )
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  modFunctionUI("table_1"),
  modFunctionUI("table_2"),
  modFunctionUI("table_3")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # call the modules for the editable tables and store the results
  amptable <- module1("table_1")
  refreshtable <- module2("table_2")
  
  # call the module for the table that takes inputs
  # the reactives musn't be evaluated
  module_add("table_3",
             data_input_1 = amptable,
             data_input_2 = refreshtable)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to call the input$var from a selectInput in the main UI rather than from the module?

Comment: Yes, it can be done.  It is up to you where you want to place it.  I was just trying to make your program work.

Comment: Could you explain how the call works? In my module when I add another argument to my module function and use reactive({input$var}), an error comes up Error in ==: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types. 

`
module1 <- function(id, choice) {
...
data <- reactiveValues()
      observeEvent(choice, {data$table <- test[test$num == as.numeric(choice),]}, ignoreInit = FALSE)
...
}
           
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # call the modules for the editable tables and store the results
  amptable <- module1("table_1", reactive({input$var}))
}
`

Comment: Sorry for the confusing comment, I made an edit within the original question

Comment: Please note that moving `selectInput` to the main `ui` should be considered carefully as you are calling `modFunctionUI()` 3 times.  That requires 3 selectInput in the main `ui`.  That reduces the benefits of module programming.  My suggestion is for you to go through some online training on modules programming.  SO is mainly for resolving issues when you are stuck.

Comment: As you made it reactive, you call it with `()` as in `observeEvent(choice(), {data$table ...})`